# Prevent close tooltip when scroll on mobile angular 7

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I have tooltips, I'm using ng-bootstrap, and I would like to have a feature like this: If you click a button, tooltip shows, if you click outside, tooltip hides, but If you have open tooltip and scroll on mobile, button can't be hidden. How can I do this? Because now when I swipe on mobile, tooltip is hidden.

```
<button [autoClose]="'outside'" triggers="click" placement="auto" ngbTooltip="Test">Click</button>
```

I'm using Angular 7 and ng-bootstrap 4.2.1